# Function in PHP to handling double quotes in strings

Tags: php, csv

i read a xml file and with php i edit some values and put them into a csv file.

Some values could look like this:

"lorem; ipsum
"lorem ipsum
"lorem ipsum"
"lorem; ipsum"
lorem; ipsum
lorem "test" ipsum
"lorem "test" ipsum"
"lorem "te;st" ipsum"
"lorem "test" ipsum"
"lorem "test" ip;sum"

These values should put into the csv file the way they are.

I could edit these values like this:

- "lorem; ipsum            -> """lorem; ipsum"

  "lorem ipsum             -> """lorem ipsum"

  "lorem ipsum"            -> """lorem ipsum"""

  "lorem; ipsum"           -> """lorem; ipsum"""

  lorem; ipsum             -> "lorem; ipsum"

  lorem "test" ipsum       -> "lorem ""test"" ipsum"

  "lorem "test" ipsum"     -> """lorem ""test"" ipsum"

  "lorem "te;st" ipsum"    -> """lorem ""te;st""

  "lorem "test" ipsum"     -> """lorem ""test"" ipsum"""

  "lorem "test" ip;sum"    -> """lorem ""test"" ip;sum"""

But this way need a lot of if statements.

Is there an php function to handle it easier?

regards,
ebody

Comment: what is your code..? fyi, there is [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function - but i never tried it before.

Comment: What is your strategy for escaping double quotes? Is it just putting extra quotes surrounding them? this doesn't look like a good workaround. In most cases you will get more problems. Say, for example, that your input text is like this: `""lorem "" test;;" ipsum"""`. What would be the strategy then? As you see, it would be impossible to tell which quotes are part of the content and which ones are 'extra'. I would suggest to replace quotes with some other character or sequence, or escaping them, like this `" => \"`. RegEx might help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Try addslashes().

More details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: But if i open the csv i have values like  \"lorem \"test\" ip;sum\".

Comment: Is there any particular reason you **need** to use just quotes to escape quotes? Your own example listing of substitutions is inconsistent and prone to give problems. Escaping with backslash or substituting them by other character is the way to go.